# Change class on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I've been looking around online but can't find anything to help this problem im having (at least not with my limited JS level)

I'm trying to achieve a effect that will change a .class CSS when someone scrolls or swipes down the page.

eg. 
all `<a>` tages are blue,
if the user scrolls 20px down or 50px down... all `<a`> tags turn green
and id the scrolling stops. all the tags turn back to blue

Comment: If someone would make a jsfiddle It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not make your own jsFiddle with your current code that you've tried already?

Comment: may I leave the coffee at your desk, sir?

Comment: Wendy ... Now that you had your coffee, welcome to SO. The place where people help other people solve *programming* issues. show us some code and shorten your questions to single problems, not full features. If you did this you would find out that all the answers to your problems are already in this wonderful platform.

Comment: here is how far I have gotten, sorry guys http://jsfiddle.net/raxotf4o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to bind to the scroll event, using window.onScroll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll with a function that changes the class on the element you're interested in.

```
// This is the event "onscroll" on the window object, that we're binding to and passing an
// anonymous function as the function to be executed when the event is triggered
    window.onscroll = function (event) {
      // Then here (inside the anonymous function that's being passed in), we add the class
      // "my-class" to the document body.
      document.body.classList.add("my-class");
    }
```

Note: This should give you enough information to solve the problem yourself, but I don't want to solve it for you - in this example, the function will be called every time the window is scrolled (so you'll want to add some sort of check/limit), and classList doesn't work in older browsers.

Comment: Hey ive been play around with the code, im still a litle stuck

heres how far I have gotten, if anyone could give me a hand it would be great

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/raxotf4o/